# How can i build an Online word Processor using .net.. Libraries in .net for MS word files?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm a student doing final year of my Computer Science and Engineering. For my final year project i've choosen to do an online word processor such as google docs,zoho etc.I want to implement this project in .net. This will be a ajax oriented project  and i'm well prepared with the web related part of it with ASP.net and C#.net at the server end and HTML,Javascript at the front end. But the point where i'm struck up is:

-> How can i create, edit and add MS Word features to a .doc file using VB.net or C#.net??
-> .net Library classes that will be helpful for me to create word related components as .doc files i.e how to create word using .net?
-> How can i convert a .doc file to HTML file to display it on a web browser?
-> In brief tell me how to create a word processor so that i'll be able to create it online.

```
        So, Plz reply me regarding these 4 issues so that i'll be easily able to complete my project.
```

Thanking You in Advance,

Comment: there's this awesome website that tells you everything you need to know.
http://www.google.com

but seriously, you want to build this but you have no idea how to go about this, and lack the necessary skills to search google for it. maybe you should start on something a little more basic.

on top of this why do you want to create soemthing that's been made and is freely available on the internet, you're not likely to produce a better product than google apps. no point re-inventing the wheel and all that

Comment: @zeocrash -> dude, i got wat u said! but i want to make it for a company that wants to display its doc files online and allows it to be accessed and edited by more than one person at any instance of time.

Also there r some unique but very simple custom features that i cant expect google to do, like editor in my local language [kannada], wap site for word processing etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like zeocrash said, start with something simple.

1. Try creating a simple page
   with a Rich Editor like FckEditor or
   TinyCME.
2. After that, look in google
   for a library that converts the HTML
   entered by the user into a doc or
   odf; or write your own by using
   Word's API.
3. Finally, try to customize
   your HTML editor using a combination
   of JQuery and server side code to do
   exactly what you want.